# Count characters in each line of a file?

Tags: python, macos

Any tips on how to count the amount of characters in each line of a text file, to then compare them using python?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you are looking to do. Also, show your own code attempt please and explain what issues you are currently having.

Comment: You should Google first before posting [duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416522/counting-characters-and-lines-from-a-file-python-2-7)...

Answer (score 6):

It would be helpful to have an idea of what the end goal of your code is. What information do you want to gain from comparing the number of characters on a line? I would have written this as a comment, but it's not yet an option for me since I just joined.

If you're completely lost and don't know where to begin, here are some general bits of code to get you started (this is using Python 3.x):

```
file = open("YourFileName.txt", "r")
stringList = file.readlines()
```

The first line will open (read, hence the "r") the file in question. The second line of code goes through each line in the file and assigns them to a variable I called stringList. stringList is now a list, in which each element is a string corresponding to one line of your text file.
So,

```
print(stringList)
```

should return

```
['line0', 'line1', 'line2', 'line3', etc...]
```

It's possible that stringList could look like

```
['line0\n', 'line1\n', 'line2\n', 'line3\n', etc...]
```

depending on how your file is formatted. In case you didn't know, the '\n' is a newline character, equivalent to hitting enter on the keyboard.

From there you can create another list to hold the length of each line, and then loop through each element of stringList to store the lengths.

```
lengthList = []
for line in stringList:
    lengthList.append(len(line))
```

len(line) takes the number of characters in a string and converts it to the equivalent integer value. Your lengthList will then contain how many characters are on each line, stored as ints. If there are '\n's, you may want to use len(line) - 1, depending on what you want to do with the lengths.

I hope this is helpful; I can't help with the comparisons until you provide some code and explain more specifically what you want to accomplish.