# how to count repeated characters in text file using python

Tags: python, string, text, count, analyzer

i am beginner in python and i am trying to make a small program in python to count repeated  character in a text file

here is the code

```
import string 

def count_char(text,char):
    count = 0
    for c in text:
        if c == char:
            count +=1
        return count

filename = raw_input("Enter File name:")
with open(filename) as f:
    text=f.read()

print(count_char(text,"r"))
```

but it prints output as

```
>> 0
```

please tell me what is the wrong with my code ?

Comment: Here is your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416522/counting-characters-and-lines-from-a-file-python-2-7

Comment: Your `return` is inside the `for` loop, so it stops on the first character

Comment: len(text) returns the number of characters of a string

Comment: Jalo, the goal is not to count the total number of characters, but the number of e.g. 'a' or 'b'

Comment: @GoutamReddy: Instead of posting, who solved it, it is good practice on StackOverflow, to *accept an answer*. This is done by *clicking on the tick*. As multiple answers might be correct, try to figure out, which one explains the solution the best.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your return to be outside of the for loop. It's currently only going through 1 iteration.

Comment: why it's not counting more than 3621 ?

Comment: You might want to change it so that instead of reading the entire file, you perform a readline and count for each line. It might be a memory thing.

filename = raw_input("Enter File name:")
count = 0
with for open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        count += count_char(line, 'r')
print(count)

Answer (score 3):

Identation problem in "return count"

```
def count_char(text, char):
    count = 0
    text = list(text)
    for c in text:
        if c == char:
            count += 1
    return count


filename = raw_input("Enter File name:")
with open(filename) as f:
    text = f.read()

print(count_char(text, "r"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count how many times a given character appears in a string (or a file), you can use the count method:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text.count('r'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use collections to get a dictionary of all the character frequencies and see how many times a character has been repeated.

```
from collections import Counter
with open(file) as f:
    c = Counter()
    for x in f:
        c += Counter(x.strip())
```

Example: the data would be stored like this:

```
Counter({'a': 3, ' ': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 3, 'e': 3, 'd': 3, 'g': 3, 'f': 3})
```