# Using a function to print the characters from a file?

Tags: python-3.x

So I have a text file, and I need to define a function to open the file, read through it, and then return and print the number of characters within the file.

So far I've got:

```
def num_chars_in_file(file):
    path = 'planets.txt'
    file_handle = open(path)
    for text in file_handle:
        file = file_handle.readlines()
        print(file)

print(f"\nProblem 1: {num_chars_in_file()}")

# I'm not sure where to go from where.
```

Comment: `text` is *already* a line from the file; you don't need to read from it "again". Just `print(text)`.

Comment: As to your actual question, can you figure out how many characters are in your file if you can figure out how many characters are on each line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the number of characters in a file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504428/find-the-number-of-characters-in-a-file-using-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a count variable to store the cumulative total of characters as you iterate over each line, something like this:

```py
def num_chars_in_file():
    path = 'planets.txt'
    file_handle = open(path)
    count = 0

    for text in file_handle:
        count += len(text.rstrip())

    file_handle.close()  # Make sure to close the file if you're not using with

    return count

print(f"\nProblem 1: {num_chars_in_file()}")
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, but can you explain what rstrip() does? I'm in my first Python class and haven't encountered it. Also, how does the function run without any parameter or argument?

Comment: When you read from a text file, there’s a hidden new line character at the end of each line. This is known as white space, and rstrip() removes the white space from the string. It would be included in the total otherwise.

Comment: @gnenadov and functions don’t necessarily need any arguments, they just often do.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('my_words.txt') as infile:
    lines=0
    words=0
    characters=0
    for line in infile:
        wordslist=line.split()
        lines=lines+1
        words=words+len(wordslist)
        characters += sum(len(word) for word in wordslist)
print(lines)
print(words)
print(characters)
```

Try this to print number of line, words and characters in the file.

Refer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504428/find-the-number-of-characters-in-a-file-using-python) more details.