# Counting characters in a file in Python

Tags: python, file, loops

I am trying to write a function that counts the number of characters in a text file and returns the result. I have the following code;

```
def file_size(filename):
    """Function that counts the number of characters in a file"""
    filename = "data.txt"
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        text = file.read()
        len_chars = sum(len(word) for word in text)
        return len_chars
```

This seemed to be working fine in my IDE when I test ran it with a text file that I created. However when I submit the code to a doctest program I get an error saying it always gives the output of 10. Any help?

Attached is a screenshot of the error message
[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9thoL.png).

Comment: Do you want to count unique characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [counting characters and lines from a file python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416522/counting-characters-and-lines-from-a-file-python-2-7)

Comment: You are counting the same thing every time... `filename = "data.txt"`

Comment: BTW: `len_chars = sum(len(word) for word in text)` is a over-engineered and I don't think is doing what you think it is doing, going by your names. You see, iterating over a string like you do: `for word in text:`  *iterates over the characters*, and doesn't split on word-boundaries just because you name the iterator variable `word`.  So you see, there is *no need* to call `len` on each `word` then `sum` it... since `len` is always `1`. But you could have just called `len(text)` and have gotten the same answer!

Answer (score 4):

You don't use the argument of the function but overwrite `filename` with the constant `"data.txt"`:

```
def file_size(filename):
    """Function that counts the number of characters in a file"""
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return len(file.read())
```

Comment: Not memory efficient

Comment: @Chris_Rands: not the topic here.

Comment: Depending on the particulars, one might prefer raw speed.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Agreed, but Python (especially Python 3) is normally based on the philosophy that, unless otherwise stated memory efficiency should be the priority, for example, this is how `itertools` is implemented

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Python's philosophy is simplicity. And there is no equally simple memory efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Super efficient solution for ASCII files (runs in theta(1)):

```
import os
print(os.stat(filename).st_size)
```

Comment: Not necessarily what you want, unless you assume the file is in some 8-bit encoding, like ascii. At least, it won't be equivalent to the OPs answer. To be equivalent, the file would need to be in `rb` mode.

Comment: What juanpa said. This counts bytes, not chars, so it won't always give the correct number, eg if the file is encoded as UTF-8 and it contains non-ASCII chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the file size of an ASCII file, you should use [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat) :

```
import os

def file_size(filename):
    st = os.stat(filename)
    return st.st_size
```

The big advantage with this function is that there's not need to read the file. Python simply asks the filesystem for the file size.

Comment: Note, not necessarily the number of characters, unless it is encoded in an 8-bit encoding like ascii.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sum()` with a generator expression around `iter(partial(f.read, 1), '')`, taking inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25611913/6260170):

```
from functools import partial

def num_chars(filename):
    """Function that counts the number of characters in a file"""
    with open(filename) as f:
        return sum(1 for _ in iter(partial(f.read, 1), ''))
```

The main advantage of this is approach compared to using `f.read()` is that it is *lazy*, so you don't read the whole file into memory.